# Accessing Google Drive SDK from Perl

Tags: google-drive-api

I have couple of Perl scripts that uploads / reads files from Google drive. Is it possible to access Google drive with Perl Api, or I need to switch to python or some scripting languages that Google supports.

Answer (score 2):

We have a REST API. You can use any language to implement your own client, you don't have to use one of the client libraries we support.

- An overview of the resources are here: https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference
- Auth is explained on https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2#webserver
- File upload is explained on https://developers.google.com/drive/manage-uploads

Comment: My application from linux should upload files to my google drive account even on offline mode without any user intervention or Web Browser support.i.e By not getting Authorization code from browser and then passing it to proceed.                                                                1.Is there any way for doing it in end-end app without user intervention.                                                           2. What kind of application I should choose? 1.Installed App, 2.Client project, 3.Web Project, 4.device project.?

Answer (score 1):

I just found a nice cpan module for talking to Google drive. So it might be as useful to you as it will be to me, because I just started playing with it. The only thing that is weird about it is that it needs to run install script to create the initial credentials on your machine.

http://search.cpan.org/~mschilli/Net-Google-Drive-Simple-0.03/lib/Net/Google/Drive/Simple.pm#SYNOPSIS

Comment: This uses v2 API.   Google::API::Client could be of use as well, it can use service account credentials (no 'install script' required), but documentation is rather sparse.

Answer (score 0):

You can download (not upload) *without authentication* using a link created by the "Share" button in Google Drive.  When creating the link, click the "gear" icon in the share popup and change the option to "Viewers and commenters can see the option to download, print, and copy" (the other choice gives full edit permission, which you probably don't want).   Then, back on the main "share" screen, select "Anyone with the link can access...".

The resulting URL will look like
`https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/<DOC_FILE_ID>/edit?usp=sharing`

Extract the <DOC_FILE_ID> and use it like this to download the spreadsheet (format=pdf also works):

```
wget -O result.xlsx https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/<DOC_FILE_ID>/export?format=xlsx
```

(or the equivalent using a Perl library)

There are other URL forms for non-spreadsheets, see https://www.howtogeek.com/747810/how-to-make-a-direct-download-link-for-google-drive-files/

I realize this does not answer the OP who wanted both upload & download; but for anyone who only needs read-only access to known Google docs, this is easy and avoids the Google authentication goop.  Bear in mind, the DOC_FILE_ID gives anyone on the Internet read-only access, so be very careful if the doc is sensitive!